# Converting units of $G$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, physical-constants, unit-conversion

I want to convert $G$ from $\rm m^3 \:kg^{-1} \:s^{-2}$ to the units $\rm km^3 \: kg^{-1} min^{-2}$.

How can this be done?

I want to know what $6.67\times 10^{-11} \:\rm m^3 \:kg^{-1} \:s^{-2}$ is in $\rm km^3 \: kg^{-1} min^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Unit symbols work identically to algebraic symbols:
$$
1\:\mathrm{kg} = 1000 \:\mathrm{m},
$$
say, or $1\:\rm min = 60 \:s$. As such, to convert from one unit set, you just substitute in the correct values of the old units in terms of the new units,
\begin{align}
G
&=6.67\times 10^{-11} \:\rm m^3 \:kg^{-1} \:s^{-2}
\\&=6.67\times 10^{-11} \:\rm (10^{-3}\:km)^3 \:kg^{-1} \:(1min/60)^{-2},
\end{align}
and bash out the resulting numerical factors as required.